# Can't get JPanel to display Entire Content

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, jtextfield

To put Basically, In Java, I have 3 different JPanels.
A Label with a JTextField in Panel 1,
A Button Panel in Panel 2,
and a second JTextField in Panel 3.

In Panel 1, I'm trying to Place the Label over top the JTextField so both components can become visible in one Panel. When I added my buttons to the Second Panel, Panel 2 overlayed the TextField or rather it wasn't visible. I tried setting the panels to different border Layouts and looked into trying SpringLayout, though either the Label is getting overwritten, or the JTextField itself.

Is there an answer to this Dilemma or something I haven't tried?
[Code Added]

```
    public class Finale extends JApplet implements ActionListener{
private JButton PostP1 = new JButton("Post Position 1");
private JButton PostP2 = new JButton("Post Position 2");
private JButton PostP3 = new JButton("Post Position 3");
private JButton PostP4 = new JButton("Post Position 4");
private JTextField ReadOut = new JTextField("Hello");
    public Finale(){
      JPanel LabelPane = new JPanel();
  JPanel ButtonPane = new JPanel();
      ButtonPane.add(PostP1);
  ButtonPane.add(PostP2);
  ButtonPane.add(PostP3);
  ButtonPane.add(PostP4);
      JLabel Welcome = new JLabel("example text");
      LabelPane.add(Welcome);
      LabelPane.add(ReadOut);
      add(LabelPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
  add(ButtonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }
```

Comment: Probably you are not setting the layout constraints properly when calling the `add()` method. For a better layout arrangement consider using `GridBagLayout`

Comment: we have no way of knowing what you have tried.  It appears too simple, to me, to warrant wading into GridBagLayout.

Comment: Coder Posted, edited first post.